# Problem is not reproducible anymore. Should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked a question here:

[Exception while deserializing object in Debug Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003944/exception-while-deserializing-object-in-debug-mode)

The problem itself seems to have vanished without altering the code or updating the IDE. I guess a simple restart of my computer fixed it.

What should I do with the question now? Just delete it? Or should I write an answer (or comment) that a reboot fixed it?

Comment: I would delete it as the cause is not clear and *reboot your pc* is not an answer that is useful for others...

Comment: You can write a comment but don't delete it.

Comment: There's an off-topic close reason for this.

Comment: I think generally it depends, without looking at the question specifically ask yourself some questions: 1) Is someone likely to encounter the same issue?, 2) Have I shown some useful debugging that might help someone? 3) Have the comments/answers provided useful clues to others who may be in the same situation?

Comment: @rene Try telling that to every IT call center ever.

Comment: @TylerH I have to start somewhere....

Comment: I have the similar problem with other question with the difference it was reproducible for a week or so (with many reboots, etc.) but now I can't reproduce on the same environment. Not sure whether it influences closing of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure  you can't recreate the issue in a separate, smaller program? If so, you can flag for closure.

- Click "flag"
- "off topic because..."
- "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

I do not know how this affects the formula for question bans.

---

The above works for the general case and where the question doesn't have many up votes. The OP's question has a score of 6, which [makes it harder for the community to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers. Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, so as to allow for editing and possible reopening.

If the question won't have value to others but has a high score, the owner should delete it since it will be easiest for them to do so.

Note that if there's an up voted answer, the OP won't be able to just delete it and should flag it instead.

Comment: While this seems to be correct how would I ever get 5 votes if I hadn't posted here?

Comment: You could try one of the chat rooms if you need people to help you close it. You could also leave a comment on  your question explaining that the problem went away after you restarted and you can't reproduce it.

Comment: If you need people to close vote on specific questions you can always ask in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) @Moh-Aw

Comment: If unlikely to help future readers, why not suggest deletion?

Comment: @Trobbins - Leaving it up for a while as on hold/closed gives other users having the same issue to find it and request that it be re-opened. If that happens, the OP doesn't have to take the hit of a deletion and that if it doesn't happen the system will eventually delete it. I thought the question had a score of 0 but it's the one answer that has a 0 score.

Comment: @Trobbins - I just updated my answer to consider the case of an up voted question.

Comment: Ok, it's marked as off-topic now.